# Validar Fecha de Mysql con la de mi proyecto

Tags: java, mysql

La idea es validar la fecha actual de Mysql al momento de ejecutar una query con la de mi proyecto, de igual forma  que cuando sean iguales pasen a las siguientes querys.

La forma de hacerla es la siguiente pero hay algo que no me cuadra (SOY ULTRA JR).

```
boolean validarfecha = sql.query(query2)=fecha;
    public void Date Query;

        if (validarfecha){

            String query  = "SELECT * FROM tb022_users WHERE rut LIKE '25502326-8 %'";
            String query1 = "SELECT * FROM tr022_010_user_roles WHERE id_user = 1";
            sql.query(query);
            sql.query(query1);
        } return false;


        sql.desconectarBD();
    }
```

Comment: Esta línea: `boolean validarfecha = sql.query(query2)=fecha;` no tiene absolutamente nada de sentido. Un único `=` sirve para asignar, no comparar... Luego declaras un `public void Date Query;` que no tiene sentido tampoco meter un `public` ahí, puesto que asumo que estás dentro de un método ya... ni tampoco tiene sentido que sea `void Date`, `void` significa que no tiene tipo, `Date` es un tipo... de todas maneras, `void` se utiliza para métodos no en variables. Lo que tienes es un fallo de base bastante gordo, dado que parece que no sabes declarar métodos/variables

Comment: La pregunta es: esto compila?

Comment: Te recomiendo que repases la teoría de cómo declarar variables *dentro* de métodos, además de cómo declarar un método correctamente. El `return false;` tampoco tiene sentido ahí... todo el código que has puesto, parece que lo hayas puesto **al azar** ahí. Eso en programación no sirve. No se puede hacer nada *al azar*, todo tiene una razón de ser. Repasa la teoría, busca algunos ejemplos y si tienes un error concreto, podrás venir aquí a preguntar. De hecho, te recomiendo leer [ask] y hacer el [tour] antes de preguntar aquí, porque no cuadra que tengamos que hacerte todo el código de 0 sin más!

Comment: Comparro lo que dicen los comentario de arriba. Además de eso, deberías agregar más código para tener mayor contexto de lo que estas intentando hacer